# Codeception submitForm failing with SQL error

Tags: php, testing, laravel-4, codeception

I am trying out some Codeception tests with Laravel 4.2 and I am getting a strange error. My test is attempting to create a user but fails due to an SQL update error. Here is the test:

```
<?php
    $I = new FunctionalTester($scenario);
    $I->wantTo('create a new user');

    $I->amLoggedAs(User::find(1));
    $I->amOnPage('/users');
    $I->click('Create New');
    $I->amOnPage('/users/create');
    $I->submitForm('#create-users-form', ['firstName' => 'John', 'lastName' => 'Doe', 'emailAddress' => 'jd@yahoo.com']);
    $I->amOnPage('/users');
    $I->seeInDatabase('users', ['emailAddress' => 'jd@yahoo.com']);
```

The output generated by this test:

```
There was 1 error:

---------
1) Failed to create a new user in CreateNewUserCept (tests/functional/CreateNewUserCept.php)
Couldn't submit form "#create-users-form",{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","emailAddress":"jd@yahoo.com"}:
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such column: email (SQL: update "users" set "email" = jd@yahoo.com, "password" = y$/vao8Yx/nRjGEGdg0NaN/ugr3O.KZjekVqJw7tq71uGsgFcp.SkA2, "updated_at" = 2014-10-02 20:14:39 where "id" = 27)

Scenario Steps:
5. I submit form "#create-users-form",{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","emailAddress":"jd@yahoo.com"}
4. I am on page "/users/create"
3. I click "Create New"
2. I am on page "/users"
1. I am logged as "{** actual user detail **}"
```

It fails on step 5. Why would an update query be running, and why would it be looking for `email`?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your Users Controller and User Model?

Comment: And does the page work if you do it manually?